# Is a compensated Poisson process uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, uniform-integrability

Let $(N_t)_t$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$. Define
$$
\bar{N}_t = N_t - \lambda t
$$
which is clearly a martingale. My question is: is $\bar{N}$ uniformly integrable?
I strongly suspect the answer is NO, but if I try to compute $\mathbb{E}(\bar{N}_{T_i})$ I always get $0$. Here $T_i$ is the $i$-th jump time of $N$.
In other words I am not able to give a simple example of a stopping time $T$ such that
$\mathbb{E}(\bar{N}_T) \neq \mathbb{E}(\bar{N}_0)$

Thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: Or show $E(|\overline{N}_t|)$ is unbounded.

Comment: thanks!! As far as I understand, one way to prove it is provided in your answer by means of the CLT. Is there any other way (e.g. is it possible to compute $\mathbb{E}(|\bar{N}_t|)$ directly)?

Comment: I do not think that $E(|\bar N_t|)$ has a nice expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the central limit theorem, $\bar N_t/\sqrt{\lambda t}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $Z$ hence $P[|\bar N_t|\geqslant\sqrt{\lambda t}]\to P[|Z|\geqslant1]\gt0$ when $t\to\infty$.

In particular, $E[|\bar N_t|]\geqslant\sqrt{\lambda t}\cdot P[|\bar N_t|\geqslant\sqrt{\lambda t}]\to\infty$ hence $(\bar N_t)$ is not uniformly integrable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Is it possible to find a stopping time $T$ (necessarily unbounded, of course) such that $\mathbb{E}(\bar{N}_T) \neq \mathbb{E}(\bar{N}_0)$?

Comment: The first hitting time $T$ of the set $(1,+\infty)$ by $\bar N$ is almost surely finite and $1\lt\bar N_T\lt2$ almost surely hence $E(\bar N_T)\ne0$.